# Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve at the given point. $y = 1+2x-x^3$ at $(1,2)$

Tags: derivatives

I have the equation $y = 1+2x-x^3$ and the point $(1,2)$.

When I work it out I come up with the derivative of $2-3x^2$.

When I apply the point I come up with a slope of $-1$ and a tangent line of $y=4-x$.

Can someone work it out and confirm my answer or show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: To@wolfcall:  what did you do to get $4-x$?

Comment: We get that the tangent line has equation of shape $y=-x+b$. When $x=1$, we have $y=2$, so $b=3$.

Comment: I cannot keep track of numbers very well. I wrote it incorrectly and it almost cost me the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the point-slope formula to obtain the equation of the line, given $m = -1$ and $(x_0, y_0) = (1,2)$, which is given by:

$$y - y_0 = m(x - x_0):$$

$$ y - 2 = -(x - 1) \iff y = -x + 3$$

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. Thank you. This problem has been driving me nuts for 2 days. I had a major brain fart and replaced a 1 with a 2.

Comment: You're welcome. You're work is fine, up to the equation of the line, so take heart.

Comment: Also don't leave cal homework until last minute and cause me to rush it. And have no one to help me find my mistake. I love the internet.  Good to know I understand the concept it is just rushing to rewrite it that caused the error.

Comment: @amWhy: Also needs a TU! +1